# Getting ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError, even though param is permitted.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

### Trying to submit an ActiveModel form in rails4, and getting this error;

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
```

This is the active admin page where the data is submitted through the form:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Network do
  permit_params :name
```

These are the params that are coming through:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "network"=>{"name"=>"Acme, Inc."}, "commit"=>"Save Network"}
```

`name` is the only param that is coming through, and it is a permitted param. So, why is it giving me this error?

Comment: Try putting it as `[:name]`

Comment: Thank you, @jaspreet21anand, but that does not work. I still get the `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I discovered the culprit that was responsible for the error.

I was having these lines:

```
network = Network.new(params[:network])
network.admin ||= User.new(params[:network].andand[:admin])
```

But after changing `params` to `permitted_params` like bellow

```
network = Network.new(permitted_params[:network])
network.admin ||= User.new(permitted_params[:network].andand[:admin])
```

Everything worked fine.
Thank you all